# Delay between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear when bad internet connection

Tags: ios

My application has a problem: when internet connection is bad, there's a delay (about 4s) between the end of `viewWillAppear` and the beginning of `viewDidAppear`. But when internet is normal, problem does not happen!

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [_btnMenu setBadgeTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self updateNotification];
    [_btnMenu setBadgeEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 0, 8)];
    [_btnMenu setHideWhenZero:YES];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [WSProgressHUD dismiss];        
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [super setUpLocalizationString];
    willRoute = NO;


}
```

Comment: Can you give us more information? Normally these callbacks have nothing to do with internet connection. Maybe you are doing something that blocks main thread in viewWillAppear?

Comment: @skillerman14 : @batu is right. Please share your `viewWillAppear` and  `viewDidAppear` code. Then we can tell whats wrong.

Comment: Probably running some thread blocking internet call.

Comment: i updated my code above. I dont use any request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure, you are doing some operation(such as internet checking or any other network operations) on main thread which is blocking the app execution. DO the internet checking on background thread.

**Objective-C**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // DO the internet checking or any other network operations here
});
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    print("This is run on the background queue")
    // DO the internet checking or any other network operations here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please use instrument to find out which is taking more time. if something based on internet, then check internet connection first, then go for internet based statement(on backgound if poosble)

For checking internet:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/Reachability